# What's the point of a stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Are they useful for anything outside of a database administrator?  If I understand them correctly it's merely queries that can be saved directly into MySQL, so it'd be useless for any web development team to use them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Stored procedures are ***code that runs on the database server.***

They have a number of uses.  Think: *If I could run code directly on the database server, what could I use that for?*

Among their many uses, stored procedures can be used to *shift some of the processing load to the database server*, to *reduce network traffic,* and to *improve security.*

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stored_procedure

Comment: Not to mention it allows you to use stuff like PL/V8 and write DB-side *javascript*

Comment: @mfrankli: Of course.  My answer does not suggest using stored procedures for everything; use them only when they are useful and the benefits outweigh the costs.  Remember that not everything that happens on a database server involves retrieval of data.

Answer (score 6):

Here are two good, simple advantages not covered in the other answers:

- Security - parameterized stored procedures are safer than contencating strings for SQL (Google SQL Injection for about a million documents on this)  However, parameterized queries are also good for this if your language supports them
- Simplification of Maintenance - It's a heck of a lot easier to update a stored procedure than to recompile code and re-deploy.  In my 15 years of development I've learned this the hard way.  If there's a chance the query might change, put it in a stored proc.  It's SOOO much easier to work with than having to recompile and redeploy code.

**Added**

They also reduce network chatter.  If you have a lot of complex wueries to run, you can have them all in one stored procedure, and your app only needs to make one call to do all the work.

Also, in most platforms, stored procedures have performance benefits. In SQL Server, for example, the Database Engine optimizes and saves the executio plan to speed things up.
these links also answer your question:

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/04/13/sql-server-stored-procedures-advantages-and-best-advantage/

http://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/news/1052737/Why-use-stored-procedures

And I can't take credit for this answer, but I think this quote is a good point, even though I consider myself to be pretty skilled on both sides of the equation - there is something to be said for specialized knowledge.

> Advantage 4: Stored procedures are
>   usually written by database
>   developers/administrators. Persons
>   holding these roles are usually more
>   experienced in writing efficient
>   queries and SQL statements. This frees
>   the GUI application developers to
>   utilize their skills on the functional
>   and graphical presentation pieces of
>   the application. If you have your
>   people performing the tasks to which
>   they are best suited, then you will
>   ultimately produce a better overall
>   application.

Comment: I have only worked in PHP, so compiling isn't an issue.  I can see where that'd be a pain... +1 for "Advantage 4" inclusion, very nice.

Answer (score 4):

Think of a stored procedures as a library function.  Do you want to rewrite sqrt (for example) every time you have to compute a square root or would you rather call a function to do it?

That's the benefit (in a nutshell) of stored procedures.

Comment: C'mon people, when you downvote, tell me why (especially 2 years after the fact)

Answer (score 2):

Stored procedures have lots of benefits. Among other things they help decouple application code from the database tables, simplify database maintenance and versioning and help take the best advantage of DBMS features such as query parameterisation, optimisation and security.

> it'd be useless for any web
>   development team to use them

Huh? Stored procedures are extremely useful for any developers who need to use a database that supports them.

Answer (score 1):

Stored Procedures can do far more than just query the database. They can contain any T-SQL statement. So you could use them to perform business logic, execute queries, do backups etc.

Many companies have a policy that all database activity is to be done via stored procedures. So, in now way would I say that a web development team would have no use for them. They might make great use of them.

On the other hand, in our company, we're not using them much of all for our next generation manufacturing applications. We're using an ORM (Linq-To-SQL) instead, and have very little use for stored procedures, at this point. I suspect though we'll still use them somewhat, in order to avoid several trips back and forth to the server. Somethings are just more efficient if done in a stored procedure, if you're already doing work on the server anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Back in the 90's, stored procedures were the safest way to prevent anyone from accessing the data tables directly.

At first hand, they were more likely to counter security issues. Secondly, they were meant to be easier to work with the data, as there were no ORM tools as today's.

In the days, they are meant for complex transactions mainly. When I say complex, I mean something that cannot be solved with simple CRUD operations such as **NHibernate** or **Entity Framework** can do.

So, when a stored procedure only perform a `SELECT`, an `INSERT`, an `UPDATE` or a `DELETE`, you may be right that they are now useless somehow, as you can perform these basic repeated operations through an ORM tool. However, when you have to build a report, for instance, that requires desperate information data, and some other calculations performed, etc. and that the result is pretty complex to compute, then you better let the database engine work this out as it is designed to compute such data.

Comment: Might as well put the CRUD stuff into stored procedures from the start too, since it's difficult to know where additional business rules will be required, and stored procedures gives you that extra layer between your client programs and your data.

Comment: maybe your data is 'desperate', but mine is just 'disparate' =P

Comment: @jon_darkstar - I've seen some pretty desperate data

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what others have said about security, encapsulation, performance, etc. of stored procedures, I'd like to add that the usefulness of stored procedures increases with the richness of the stored procedure language.

I don't have much experience with MySQL, but as far as I know the stored procedure language is pretty limited.

T-SQL (in Microsoft SQL Server) is more capable, but has several shortcomings compared to full-featured programming languages. For example, it is not possible to declare a constant value in T-SQL, and until quite recently there was no exception handling, so error handling was a pain. There is no concept of a package, so all your code will be stand-alone procedures with no way to group them together except for a good naming convention. (Although it's true that you can write stored procedures in .NET languages.)

On the other hand, PL/SQL (in Oracle), is a full-featured programming language with complex data types, exception handling, packages for grouping procedures (with separate public and private sections), object types, and lots and lots of built-in packages that deal with everything from file access to compression and generating web pages. All that, plus seamless integration with the database and the SQL language. Entire applications can be built using PL/SQL, without "leaving the database", so to speak. Check out http://apex.oracle.com for an example of a massive (framework) application implemented in pure PL/SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you insert two rows in different tables, the second insert requires the id from the first.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO t1 (f1,f2...) VALUES (v1, v2...)";
mysql_query($sql, $conn);
$id = mysql_insert_id();
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO t2 (f1,f2,id,f3...) VALUES (v1,v2,$id,v3....);
mysql_query($sql2,$conn)l
```

You went to the database twice, two server request/response.  If you can store the process of INSERT, @id=insert id, INSERT all on the server in my_proc, you only have to do so once.

```
$sql = "CALL my_proc(arguments)";
mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: The other reasons stated in this post really don't matter if your connecting to mysql in another language as you can just code the function, in that language. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Think of them as procedures in any regular program. A way of encapsulating a chunk of logic under a single invocation method.

If you consider functions in programs useless, then this conversation ends here. If you think they're useful, then there's nowhere else to go either. Nothing forces you to use them, but they're available if you should choose to.

Comment: Functions is kind of my point, personally I'd rather have a function that contains the SQL so as not to confuse others who see my code, so they know everything has a place... perhaps I'm just not to the level you guys are...

Comment: Well, some projects are going to have common queries that are reused everywhere. Rather than having to embed the same sql in a million places, embed one stored procedure call instead. It's not just for DBAs...

Answer (score 0):

> If I understand them correctly it's
>   merely queries that can be saved
>   directly into MySQL, so it'd be
>   useless for any web development team
>   to use them.

Even with that (limited) definition, you're implying that web development teams never have any need of querying a database?  Really?

A well written set of stored procs can completely remove queries from your client application and replace all of that with calls to the procedures.  Now, I'm not saying that that's the only way of doing things, or even the right way.  There's quite the [discussion](http://www.google.com/search?q=stored+procedures+vs+inline+sql) about that going on overall.  But it is a very valid way of using them.

So, useless for a webdev team?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to all the answers given here, i would also like to point out that stored procedures are a way to save the execution plan of a query.

you may have a set of SQL statements you just call from your application, but each time you execute the query SQL server has no way of knowing that the query you just invoked is the exact same query that as the one you called a few minutes ago (which would happen very frequently in a web application). So SQL server has to repeat the all the processing again (build the query plan and execute it).

Now if the same query had been encapsulated within a stored procedure, SQL server would have saved the execution plan for that stored procedure so that each time you call the sproc, it doesn't have to recompile the execution plan all the time. (It may even cache the data based on the parameters passed to the sproc, but i dont know exactly how this works)

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to performance tune code in stored procs than what most ORMs create. It is easier to use stored procs when there are multiple applications that access the same database and might need to do the same things. It is far easier to refactor databases when all code is in stored procs because you can easily see where the changes need to be made. It is easier to use stored procs for things that don't normally hook up to ORMs like SSIS or reporting applications. Using stored procs you can limit access to only what the proc does and not allow access directly to the tables or views. This is critical in enforcing internal controls on financial data for instance and helps prevent fraud.

I've written complex procs that were well over a 1000 lines long. Try getting an ORM to write that kind of SQL. Then try to get it so that it will run without timing out.