# What are MySQL functions?

Tags: mysql, function, navicat

I use Navicat for MySQL and I see "functions". How they are used? What are they? What is their main purpose?

Comment: [what is mysql function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/functions.html)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User-defined_function

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the point of a stored procedure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227660/whats-the-point-of-a-stored-procedure)

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_functions.asp

Comment: I don't have edit powers, but if you change the wording of your question, then this question will probably stop getting voted down.  Change the title to "What is a MySQL function?" or "What are MySQL functions?".  "What is functions" is considered bad grammar in English.

Comment: wordless, grammar is not the root problem

Comment: I understand why you might think this is a duplicate question and that the answer is easily found in Google, but I disagree.  Hopefully my answer will explain things.

Comment: This question should be closed as not real.

Comment: This question should be closed as not real.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SQL functions are subprograms defined inside the database. They are basically functions that can be called from inside SQL statements, and are useful for the same reasons that calling functions in other languages are useful. Most SQL languages come with some simple important functions and user defined functions can be added. For example, MySQL contains the function count().  It can be called like so:

```
select count(some_column) from some_table;
```

This will count the number of rows that are in the some_column column of the some_table table.  You will get a response something like:

```
*|count(some_column)
1|200
```

SQL functions similar to, but different from stored procedures in SQL for these reasons:

- Functions must return a single value.  Stored procedures on the other hand, may return multiple values or even no return value.
- Functions can be placed inside select statements. Stored procedures can't.

You can find more information about functions and stored procedures here:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_functions.asp

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User-defined_function

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/functions.html

[What's the point of a stored procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227660/whats-the-point-of-a-stored-procedure)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stored_procedure

Comment: +1: Some people might argue that COUNT is an aggregate rather than a regular function, not least because of the special semantics of `COUNT(*)` and `COUNT(DISTINCT colname)`.  You might do better using LENGTH or SUBSTR or something similar as a prototypical function.